# How to read x characters from position y in a char * buffer?

Tags: c++

I am reading through a buffer (char *) and i have a cursor, where i am tracking my starting position of the buffer, is there a way to copy characters 7-64 out of the buffer, or is my best bet to just loop the buffer from poistion x to position y?

The size of the destination buffer is the result of another function dynamically computed

Initializing this returns

`variable-sized object 'version' may not be initialized`

Relevant code parts:

```
int32_t size = this->getObjectSizeForMarker(cursor, length, buffer);
cursor = cursor + 8; //advance cursor past marker and size
char version[size] = this->getObjectForSizeAndCursor(size, cursor, buffer);
```

-

```
char* FileReader::getObjectForSizeAndCursor(int32_t size, int cursor, char *buffer) {
  char destination[size];
  memcpy(destination, buffer + cursor, size);
}
```

-

```
int32_t FileReader::getObjectSizeForMarker(int cursor, int eof, char * buffer) {
  //skip the marker and read next 4 byes
  cursor = cursor + 4; //skip marker and read 4
  unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)buffer + cursor;
  int32_t objSize = (ptr[0] << 24) | (ptr[1] << 16) | (ptr[2] << 8) | ptr[3];
  return objSize;

}
```

Comment: you are right nhahtdh thats not what i ment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the pointer to `buffer` six units ahead (to get to the seventh index), and then [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html) 64-7 (57) bytes, e.g.:

```
const char *buffer = "foo bar baz...";
char destination[SOME_MAX_LENGTH];
memcpy(destination, buffer + 6, 64-7);
```

You may want to terminate the `destination` array so that you can work with it using standard C string functions. Note that we're adding the null character at the *58th* index, after the 57 bytes that were copied over:

```
/* terminate the destination string at the 58th byte, if desired */
destination[64-7] = '\0';
```

If you need to work with a dynamically sized `destination`, use a pointer instead of an array:

```
const char *buffer = "foo bar baz...";
char *destination = NULL;

/* note we do not multiply by sizeof(char), which is unnecessary */
/* we should cast the result, if we're in C++ */
destination = (char *) malloc(58); 

/* error checking */
if (!destination) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not allocate space for destination\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

/* copy bytes and terminate */
memcpy(destination, buffer + 6, 57);
*(destination + 57) = '\0';
...

/* don't forget to free malloc'ed variables at the end of your program, to prevent memory leaks */
free(destination);
```

Honestly, if you're in C++, you should really probably be using the C++ [strings library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/) and [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class. Then you can call the [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) substring method on your `string` instance to get the 57-character substring of interest. It would involve fewer headaches and less re-inventing the wheel.

But the above code should be useful for both C and C++ applications.

Comment: Just curious why is it -7 that is dependent on my cursor?

Comment: The `64-7` is just to show you how many bytes you're copying over. You could replace this with 57.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question. Are you saying you *don't* want to copy part of the buffer? If so, my answer will not help you.

Comment: how would i create my char[] if the size comes from another function? I know i sound like an idiot and im sure at this point i am doing it wrong. I get something like | `variable-sized object 'version' may not be initialized`

Comment: Instead of a `char []`, use a `char *` and `malloc/free`. See the edited answer. It's more work, but you can size `destination` as large or as small as you like.

Comment: in the code i use / borrowed ;) to read the file they declare the original buffer like this `buffer = new char [length]` is there an advantage to this?

Comment: You're about to open a purist question that will never settle =P. Many (I among them) are pretty strict about new vs. malloc. If i'm in C, malloc, otherwise new. exceptions, object initialization, etc. all for free. the latter not that important for scalar types, etc. The only thing I wish C++ had was an object-based realloc(), that was *efficient* (not studied C++11 so ease up on me if such a thing finally exists).

Comment: If you use `new`, use an according `delete` at the end of the lifespan of the variable. `new/delete` are similar (not identical) to `malloc/free`. If you're using C++, take advantage of the classes it offers. You're probably better off using a C++ `string`, I think, unless you are careful about memory management.

Comment: the main reason i am using chars are because of the format of file i am reading... i think moving some things to strings will make sense eventually. i just really need the data at some points on a character by character basis..... i think.

Comment: Also, if you're ultimately doing this for reading *bytes* (and judging by your posts, you are) then un-sign your chars. if it is, in fact, real *character* data, then keep the chars. For byte-work, you don't want potential sign extensions mucking with your results until *you* want them to. Some don't care much, I don't like surprises.